# ¿ Cómo insertar una vista usando html.partial en un tooltip?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html5, ajax

¿Cómo insertar una vista usando html.partial en un tooltip ?

El html.partial contiene una simple grilla y eso lo quiero visualizar en un tooltip de chart (api de google) al presionar la barra. Espero me haya dejado entender y puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Es el código que estoy probando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el error que me sale ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como se ven las barras y quiero que se muestren ahí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes tratar primero de hacer render del partialview en un string y con @html.Raw agregarlo al script, en SO en ingles hay una muy buena respuesta para como hacer render y guardarlo en un string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string

Answer (score 1):

No usas html.partial si estas trabjando con tooltip del lado del cliente

Tienes que usas codigo cliente o sea `javascript` o `jquery`, lo mejor es este ultimo.

La idea ver la forma de tener un evento cuando se activa el tooltip al pasar el mouse y en este realziar una llamada `$.ajax` a un action en el controller el cual realizara el render del html y enviara la respuesta

[AJAX calls to ASP.NET MVC action methods using jQuery](http://bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/)

En realidad haya varias formas de invocar un action desde codigo cliente, mencione el `$.ajax` pero tambine puedes usar el `$.get`, `$.post` o sino el `.load()`

La idea es que la llamada al action sea dinamica desde el cliente, sin submit de la view y el partial view lo inyectes en el div que tooltip cuando se pasa el mouse